# Sliding window protocol

Tags: communication, data, protocol

In the sliding window protocol when the receiver sends RRn to the sender the receiver's window is shifted to the right now starting at the n position correct?

Suppose this is the window of the receiver(third from top to bottom):

[image]

When the receiver sends RR11 to the sender the window then becomes 11 10 9 8 , correct?

Comment: An illustration would go a long way in helping us understand what left and right mean in this context. An image of the respective page of the book or class note would be even better.

Comment: Jun, there isn't a global "sliding window" standard that everyone is required to obey and for me to refer to -- unless you want to provide one. Otherwise, the behavior is up to the implementor. For example, you write, *"when the receiver sends RRn to the sender the receiver's window is shifted to the right now starting at the n position"* and then add this question, *"correct?"* How would we know if that description is correct?? (Unless we were looking at some documentation about the algorithm and behavior? Which you may have but I know I certainly do not have.)

Comment: @jonk I dont know I was taught it in university and I want to know if I understand it correctly.I am talking about the standard version of the protocol.

Comment: @JunSeo-He Well, if you control both ends of the wire then you get to decide what you want to do, applying what you learned but in your own novel way. If you don't control both ends of the wire, then you will need to know what the other end ***expects***. And for that, you will need to find appropriate documentation or contact the supplier. I'm pretty certain that there's no global standard, no *ONE LAW* that everyone is forced to obey under penalty of criminal punishment. (Not in US, anyway.) Lacking global enforcement means you need to collect information for any particular circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jonk explained in the comments, there is not a unique sliding window protocol. I've found this slide [here](https://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/coe/radwan/PPT/COE341_Chapter07.ppt) that may clear up the concept, in general terms:

[image]

So RR4 would mean that all frames up to 3 were received and the receiver is ready for the 4th one. This controls the transmitting window size accordingly, even if this frame has already been sent.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful.